# Converting bytea back to varchar

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres when I want to save a varchar to a bytea column, this is made easy by an implicit conversion. So I can simply execute

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_bytea_col = 'This varchar will be converted' WHERE id = 1;
```

I use this all the time. However, I would like to occasionally see the contents of this column as a varchar. IDEs will handle this for you, but I would prefer in my use case to return the results with the bytea converted back to a varchar.

Of course I've tried something like this, among more complex options:

```
select my_bytea_col::VARCHAR from my_table WHERE id = 1
```

This, however, doesn't return my original readable text. How else can I convert my bytea back to the original varchar after postgres's implicit conversion in updates and inserts like the one above?

Comment: Why are you storing plain text in a bytea anyway? That's a really bad idea to begin with.

Comment: This just happens to be how the table is set up at the moment. Could you please explain what you think is problematic about this?

Comment: Actually, I recall now that this column was made a bytea because these values can get quite large, and I believe the rationale was that bytea would be more efficient. Is that incorrect or is there a better reason not to use bytea here?

Comment: No, that assumption is not correct. A `text` column can store just as much as a `bytea` column.

Comment: Will a text column be as compact? Some quick tests on my end suggest it won't be, but the difference is somewhat small in the cases I was looking at

Comment: It's compressed just like bytea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the string encoding is UTF-8, you could use

```
SELECT convert_from(my_bytea_col, 'UTF8')
FROM my_table
WHERE id = 1;
```

If the encoding is different, you need to supply the appropriate second argument (e.g. `LATIN1`) to `convert_from`.

May I remark that I consider it not a good idea to store text strings as `bytea`?